# Headers in responsive design.

Tags: css, responsive-design, header, seo

I have a website with 5 sections and 5 headers

```
<section>
    <h1>this is the header</h1>
</section>
```

when the responsive styleseet kicks in the designer adds a section title, which should logically now be the h1.

```
<section>
    <h2>this is the NEW section header for mobile</h2>
    <h1>this is the header</h1>
</section>
```

Now this is obviously wrong as the h2 proceeds the h1. This is the solution I currently but seems wrong too.

```
<section>
    <div class="section-header">this is the NEW section header for mobile</div>
    <h1>this is the header</h1>
</section>
```

Wha is best practice here.

Comment: because the second is an additional bit of content.

Comment: OK, but SEO questions are off-topic for SO - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281367/where-to-find-answers-to-seo-questions

Answer (score 0):

In the end I think this is a reasonable solution

```
<section>
    <div class="section-header">this is the NEW section header for mobile</div>
    <h1>this is the header</h1>
</section>
```